# Dapper Query incorrectly maps the entity ID

Tags: join, dapper

I have 2 entity classes:

```
public class PostTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public class PostTagIndex
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PostTagId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to draw attention to the fact that both of them have the same field named 'Id'.

Next, I use Query(...) method this way:

```
List<PostTag> postTags
    = cn.Query<PostTag>(postTagsSql, new { postId }).AsList();
```

Here is the generated SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
            SELECT *
            FROM [PostTags] AS pt
            JOIN [PostTagIndexes] AS pti
            ON pt.[Id] = pti.[PostTagId]
            WHERE ([PostId] = @postId)',N'@postId int',@postId=3035
```

And here is its result:

```
Id      Alias   Name    Level   Id      PostId  PostTagId
1014    name1   Name1   0       2020    3035    1014
2014    name2   Name2   1       3021    3035    2014
```

So, the result has two 'Id' columns because of joining and selecting all the columns.

I expect to have the first column 'Id' values put in the PostTag.Id. Isn't it logical? But in fact, it takes the second 'Id' column as PostTags' ids. Of course, I can write `SELECT pt.*` instead of just `SELECT *`, but anyway why doesn't it take the very first appropriate column name instead of skipping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that the first ID is being skipped. I suspect it is being over-written by second.

So, Dapper mapper module starts the mapping. It find first ID column. It maps it correctly. Then it also maps other columns. Then it again finds the ID column and maps it **correctly** again.

As I said above, this is what I suspect. You may want to have a look at Dapper source code to make sure.

As you said in your question, `SELECT pt.*` is one solution. Other may be to use different alias for `pti.ID AS PTI_ID` or something.

Data type is also considered while mapping. But this is something you cannot change I guess.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962601/5779732) discusses about mapping duplicate columns when one of them is `null`.

Comment: I think you're right, it maps `Id` twice. I added a pull-request with a fix, but it broke some tests:
https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/pull/991

Comment: @Sergey: I personally think the way Dapper is working is correct. `Distinct().` (as you modified on github) will fetch one field out of multiples. But this will create more trouble than solution. Which field is selected? Why that? Why not other? Too many if-and-but.

Comment: @Sergey: The better solution I can imagine of is that Dapper should throw an exception if duplicate column name is found. That way, user know in advance what wrong is going on. User then can correct the code in whatever best way for given situation.

Comment: I agree with any solution which is better than a quiet setting of a wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance you're using Dapper incorrectly I'm afraid. Your SQL is returning 2 entities worth of columns but you're asking Dapper to map to only one of them.

You should either use the multi-mapping query or select just those columns that are needed for the PostTag entity.